# Inside Function getting recognized as a Pointer 

Tags: c++, function, pointers, function-pointers

When I try to compile, I get two error messages, which I thought about for a while and could not resolve. Could somebody shed some light on my problem?

errors:

```
leeftijd.cc: In function ‘int main()’:
leeftijd.cc:50:49: error: invalid conversion from ‘int’ to ‘int (*)(int, int, int)’ [-fpermissive]
leeftijd.cc:10:9: error:   initializing argument 1 of ‘int leeftijd_in_maanden(int (*)(int, int, int), int, int, int)’ [-fpermissive]
```

Code:

```
#include <iostream>  // Line one
//line two
#define PEILJAAR 2012   
#define PEILMAAND 9
#define PEILDAG 23

using namespace std;

int leeftijd_in_jaren(int _geboortejaar, int _geboortemaand, int _geboortedag); 
int leeftijd_in_maanden(int _leeftijd_in_jaren(int _geboortejaar, int _geboortemaand, int _geboortedag),
            int _geboortejaar, int _geboortemaand, int _geboortedag);

bool onjuiste_geboortedag(int _geboortedag, int _geboortejaar);
bool onjuiste_geboortemaand(int _geboortemaand, int _geboortejaar);
bool onjuiste_geboortejaar(int _geboortejaar);

int main()
{
        int geboortejaar, geboortemaand, geboortedag;   

    cout << " Geef uw geboortejaar" << endl;
    cin >> geboortejaar;
    if( onjuiste_geboortejaar(geboortejaar) )
    {
        cout << "U voldoet niet aan de eisen." << endl; 
        return 0;
    }  

    cout << " Geef uw geboortemaand" << endl;
    cin >> geboortemaand;
    if( onjuiste_geboortemaand(geboortemaand, geboortejaar) )
    {
        cout << "U voldoet niet aan de eisen." << endl;
        return 0;   
    } 

    cout << " Geef uw geboortedag" << endl;
    cin >> geboortedag;
    if( onjuiste_geboortedag(geboortedag, geboortejaar) )
    {
        cout << "U voldoet niet aan de eisen." << endl;
        return 0;
    } 

    cout << "U bent "
    << leeftijd_in_jaren(geboortejaar, geboortemaand, geboortedag)
    << " jaar en "
    << " maanden en uw leeftijd in maanden is "
    << leeftijd_in_maanden( leeftijd_in_jaren(geboortejaar, geboortemaand, geboortedag),
                geboortejaar, geboortemaand, geboortedag)
    << "."   << endl;
    return 0;
}

int leeftijd_in_jaren(int _geboortejaar, int _geboortemaand, int _geboortedag) 
{
    int _leeftijd_in_jaren;
    if(_geboortemaand < PEILMAAND || _geboortemaand == PEILMAAND && _geboortedag <= PEILDAG)
    {_leeftijd_in_jaren = PEILJAAR - _geboortejaar;}
    else{_leeftijd_in_jaren = PEILJAAR - _geboortejaar - 1;}
    return _leeftijd_in_jaren;
}

int leeftijd_in_maanden(int _leeftijd_in_jaren(int _geboortejaar, int _geboortemaand, int _geboortedag),
            int _geboortejaar, int _geboortemaand, int _geboortedag)
{
    int _leeftijd_in_maanden = 
    _leeftijd_in_jaren(_geboortejaar, _geboortemaand, _geboortedag) * 12 + _geboortemaand;
    return _leeftijd_in_maanden;
}


bool onjuiste_geboortejaar(int _geboortejaar) 
{return((PEILJAAR - _geboortejaar) < 10 || (PEILJAAR - _geboortejaar) > 100);}

bool onjuiste_geboortemaand(int _geboortemaand, int _geboortejaar)
{
    return( (PEILJAAR - _geboortejaar) == 10  && _geboortemaand > PEILMAAND || 
        (PEILJAAR - _geboortejaar) == 100 && _geboortemaand > PEILMAAND ||
        _geboortemaand < 0 || _geboortemaand > 12);
} 

bool onjuiste_geboortedag(int _geboortedag, int _geboortejaar)
{   
    return( PEILDAG <= _geboortedag  && (PEILJAAR - _geboortejaar) == 10 || 
    PEILDAG >= _geboortedag  && (PEILJAAR - _geboortejaar) == 100||
    _geboortedag < 0   || _geboortedag > 31); 
}
```

Comment: BTW which amazing language names these variables have got???

Comment: @user1655481: I'm fairly sure it's Dutch.

Answer (score 0):

```
int leeftijd_in_maanden(int _leeftijd_in_jaren(int _geboortejaar, int _geboortemaand, int _geboortedag),int _geboortejaar, int _geboortemaand, int _geboortedag)
```

The above is invalid function pointer declaration in parameter lists.

Use:-

```
int leeftijd_in_maanden(int (*funcpoint)(int , int , int ),int _geboortejaar, int _geboortemaand, int _geboortedag)
{
    int _leeftijd_in_maanden = 
    funcpoint(_geboortejaar, _geboortemaand, _geboortedag) * 12 + _geboortemaand;
    return _leeftijd_in_maanden;
}
```

Comment: The declaration is valid; see my answer.

Answer (score 0):

In fact a function declaration in a parameter list is perfectly valid.  The rule is similar to the rule for an array parameter declaration; the type is adjusted from "function ..." to "pointer to function ...".

For example, in the following the function foo() has two parameters; the first is of type `int*`, and the second is of type `void(*)(void)`, i.e., a pointer-to-function type.

```
void foo(int not_really_an_array[20],
         void not_really_a_function(void))
{
}

int main() {
    int *int_ptr = 0;
    void (*func_ptr)(void) = 0;
    foo(int_ptr, func_ptr);
}
```

The error in the code in the question is not in the declaration of `leeftijd_in_maanden()`, it's in the call:

```
...
<< leeftijd_in_maanden( leeftijd_in_jaren(geboortejaar, geboortemaand, geboortedag),
            geboortejaar, geboortemaand, geboortedag)
...
```

The first argument, `leeftijd_in_jaren(geboortejaar, geboortemaand, geboortedag)`, has the form of a function *call*; since the function returns `int`, it's an expression of type `int`, not the pointer-to-function expected by `leeftijd_in_maanden()`.

Instead, you need to pass just the *name* of the function (which is implicitly converted to a pointer to the function):

```
...
<< leeftijd_in_maanden( leeftijd_in_jaren,
            geboortejaar, geboortemaand, geboortedag)
...
```

If you make that change (it's on line 50), the program compiles.  (I can't tell whether it's *semantically* correct because I can't read any of the identifiers; they're in Dutch, right?)

Answer (score -1):

A function declaration is not a valid parameter for a function.
Also, it is completely unnecessary in your case, as all you do is just call `leeftijd_in_jaren`, which is already visible in the scope of `leeftijd_in_maanden`.

Please try to post an actually useful [testcase](http://jcatki.no-ip.org/fncpp/TestCase) next time.

Comment: The function declaration is valid; see my answer.